# In xcode 5.0.1 "base Internationalization" can not be configured?

Tags: ios, internationalization, xcode5.0.1

I am trying to localize my app. I noticed that if I add a language every localized file become doubled. In this way it's impossible to maintain code or storyboard so I learnt that I need Base internationalization.

The problem is that I don't know where to configure the base internationalization in the Project-> Info. Unlike describe in the [link](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS-Legacy/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html), The setting is not available in xcode 5.0.1.

Does anyone know how to find the setting to configure base internationalization?

Comment: Same problem here. In this link the author talks about adding 'Use Base Internationalization', but it is not among the options.. Any help please. https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n#manual-setup